# Is there a way to abort a test cleanly?

Tags: ruby, selenium

Using Selenium, Ruby

I'm trying to learn the correct way of closing out a test should an object not exist.  For example I have a test that calls a function "Click_Login" which in turn goes to the function and returns the object reference or the text "Stop Test" if it does not exist.  That part is working correctly.

However after the browser is closed, the test continues on and tries to varLoginBtn.click and fails because *Stop Test.click* does not exist.  I thought the test would have stopped after the driver.quit and not continue on to varLoginBtn.click.

My goal is to have the test stop cleanly if an object does not exist.  I maybe doing this incorrectly.

```
        #The test.rb
        varLoginBtn = toNavigate.Click_LogIn(driver) #calls function down below.
        if varLoginBtn == "Stop Test"
            driver.quit
        end
        varLoginBtn.click  #click on the button


    #functions.rb
    #in the Class toNavigate
    #Login Button 
    def Click_LogIn(driver)
        puts "In the login"
        wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 15)
       begin
         element= wait.until{driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@xas-string='SDE_LOG_INN']")} #Log_INN is intentional I want it to fail.
        return element
       rescue 
          puts "The Login button did not exist"
          return "Stop Test"
       end
     end
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: beneath the driver.quit I added exit 1.  This allows me to stop the test cleanly.  Still my question is, Is this the most effective way to close out the test if an object does not exist?  For every function call will I need to begin and rescue?  Or should it be added to the object library?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to rescue, you have a condition if nil and you can use abort to exit script with a message

But also use snake_case for def ruby methods

```
def click_login(driver)
  puts "In the login"
  wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 15)
  if element = wait.until{driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@xas-string='SDE_LOG_INN']")} #Log_INN is intentional I want it to fail.
    return element
  else
    puts 'The Login button did not exist'
    abort 'Stop Test'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an overengineered way to do this... why not just throw an exception when this occurs and let the test die with a good message? Something like

```
...
rescue 
    raise "The Login button did not exist"
end
```

Your test library should be able to handle this and print a nice message that you can use to investigate, etc.

Read more about exceptions in ruby [here](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html).